# It it possible to setup a Windows 10 guest OS in VMware so the default internet connection is not used when the VPN is dropped?

Tags: vpn, vmware-workstation

I have the following situation: On the guest OS (Windows 10) in VMware on I use the VPN client, respectively, all traffic goes initially from the host of the Internet connection, and after it is captured by the VPN client, the problem is that if the VPN is dropped for any reason, the guest OS continues to use host IP.

Is it possible to make sure that, for example, on the guest OS, all traffic immediately goes through the VPN client on this very guest OS? Well, so that when VPN drops or breaks on the guest OS, the Internet simply disappears until the connection directly to the VPN is restored.

I understand that everything can be implemented through the same Whonix-Gateway and the like, but if in this case the VPN drops to the guest OS, then the IP from the Torus will be in blacklists and other points, I don’t really need it).

I also used VPNcheck, it cuts off the connection if the VPN drops, but to restore the connection from the VPN you need to click the switch in the VPNcheck program, and in this case, the traffic first of all goes from the host system and the host ip is accordingly fired, I don't need it.

P.S.: All this is not needed for some kind of crime in the Internet environment and other things, everything is absolutely clean, you just do not need the same ip to be fired on many guest OSes.

Original question in Russian below:

> ### Нужно чтобы при дропе ВПН не использовался интернет трафик с хоста, а чтобы на вирт. машине использовался только трафик при подключении ВПН'а
>
> у меня следующая ситуация, на гостевой ос(windows 10) использую ВПН клиент, соответственно весь трафик идет изначально с хост интернет подключения, а уже после его захватывает впн клиент, проблема в том что если впн дропается по какой либо причине, гостевая ОС продолжает использовать хост IP. Можно ли сделать так чтобы к примеру на гостевой ОС весь трафик сразу шел через ВПН клиент на этой самой гостевой ОС? Ну и чтобы при дропе или обрыве ВПН'а на гостевой ОС интернет просто пропадал до того момента пока не восстановится подключение непосредственно к ВПН'у.
> Понимаю что можно все реализовать через тот же whonix gateway и подобные, но если в таком случае дропнется ВПН на гостевой ОС, то ip с тора будет в блэклистах и прочие моменты, мне это не очень нужно).
> Также использовал VPNcheck, он обрывает связь если ВПН дропается, но чтобы восстановить подключение с ВПН'а нужно нажать переключатель в программе VPNcheck, а в таком случае трафик в первую очередь идет с хост системы и ip хоста соответственно палится, мне это не нужно.
> p.s. Все это нужно не для каких то преступление в интернет среде и прочего, все абсолютно чисто, просто не нужно чтобы на многих гостевых ОС палился один и тот же ip. Заранее благодарю каждого откликнувшегося!

Comment: Sorry you have this issue. But this site is English only. So I just ran you text through Google translate to assist you.

Comment: PS: It seems what you are looking for is a killswitch tool. A tool that will drop the whole Internet connection if the VPN connection is dropped.